# Windows 10 Universal Compiled binding (x:Bind) conflict with ViewModel

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app

I want to bind an element in a page to dependency property in code behind with compiled binding and same time bind another element to ViewModel with usual binding. But it gives a runtime error.

Here is my xaml code.

```
<Page
x:Class="XbindingProblem.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:XbindingProblem"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
mc:Ignorable="d">
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="UserDataTemplate" x:DataType="local:User">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}" />
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Age}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
        <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{StaticResource UserDataTemplate}" Content="{x:Bind CurrentUser, Mode=OneWay}"/>
    </StackPanel>        
</Grid>
```

Here CurrentUser is dependency property which is initially null and then change in run time. This gives following runtime error.

```
Incorrect type passed into template. Based on the x:DataType global::XbindingProblem.User was expected.
```

The problem is it passes the ViewModel into UserDataTemplate instead of CurrentUser dependency property when CurrentUser is null.

Can anyone have a good explanation on this problem?

Answer (score 5):

If you remove `DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"`, it will work. Why? because `{x:Bind CurrentUser}` is looking for a property called `CurrentUser` sitting inside your `MainPage.xaml.cs`. Since the `CurrentUser` is indeed a dependency property of your page, it will just work.

However, by specifying the `DataContext` of your page, the `x:Bind` is now excepting a `CurrentUser` property inside your `MainViewModel` instance, and of course it's not going to find it, so a compile-time error will be thrown.

One possible fix is to set the `this.CurrentUser` really early, even before calling `InitializeComponent`.

```
this.CurrentUser = new User();

InitializeComponent();
```

But this is IMHO not the the right way of doing things, as it's basically a racing game - it tries to populate the `ContentPresenter` before the `DataContext` gets updated, and in the end you will end up having the `TextBlock` (of which `Text` binds to `Title`) and the `ContentPresenter` attached to different contexts!

So ask yourself why you need to create a dependency property for `CurrentUser` inside a `Page` object, instead of having a normal property (with `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation) sitting inside your `MainViewModel`? I'd prefer the latter, 'cause it's more semantically correct.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You are correct up certain extent. But it works even we set the CurrentUser after `InitializeComponent()`. Not sure how data context changes after that.

Comment: It *might* work, but like I said, it's a racing game, can you guarantee that? You know what, try giving your `CurrentUser` a default value (i.e. `new PropertyMetadata(new User())`), this works too! You asked for the reason and I gave it to you - It works only because you are assigning a context to the `ContentPresenter` **before** the page's context gets updated.

Comment: I got your point about a racing game. Yes, I tried assigning a default value for `CurrentUser`. But in my case, `CurrentUser` shouldn't have a value when the app starts. Can't we prevent inheriting data context to `ContentPresenter`. I set `DataContext` of `ContentPresenter` to `{x:Null}`. But still it doesn't work.

Comment: If you really go down this way, you can manually set the pages datacontext to main in your code behind, after the CurrentUser is populated.

Answer (score 1):

The question is interesting, what I have done is just remove the datacontext and this is the code behind is similar to yours:

```
public sealed partial class BlankPage1 : Page
{
    public User CurrentUser
    {
        get { return (User)GetValue(CurrentUserProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CurrentUserProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for CurrentUser.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CurrentUserProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("CurrentUser", typeof(User), typeof(BlankPage1), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public BlankPage1()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        CurrentUser = new User() { Name = "Hello", Age = "20" };
    }
}

public class User
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Age { get; set; }
}
```

might be you have the User class in another namespace or have another class in the typeof(...) of the dependency property. Because I tested that and works. The DataContext of the page can be whatever you want it won't affect.

Then I added the datacontext just to test:

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <local:Main/>
</Page.DataContext>
```

and the code just for testing:

```
public class Main
{
    public String Title { get; } = "title";
    public User MainUser { get; set; }
}
```

And it does not throws any exception, appears the Main data and the CurrentUser data.

UPDATE. The error happens when the User is null so it is like the x:Bind is null it propagates to the Binding,To solve that (it was tough):

```
<Page x:Name="Root"
    x:Class="Deletetb.BlankPage1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Deletetb"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d" >
    <Page.DataContext>
        <local:Main/>
    </Page.DataContext>

    <Page.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="UserDataTemplate" x:DataType="local:User">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Age}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Page.Resources>
    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <StackPanel DataContext="{x:Null}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DataContext.Title, ElementName=Root}" />
            <ContentPresenter  ContentTemplate="{StaticResource UserDataTemplate}" Content="{x:Bind CurrentUser, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Where is binding defined (TextBlock) I set the datacontext to null in the parent container (StackPanel) and bind by element name, and it does not crash, also I added a wait by code to test and set the Current User and it works. That was a challenge. hope it also works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When CurrentUser is not null, it doesn't give any exception even without removing the data context. But in my case, CurrentUser shouldn't have a value when the app starts. Not sure why it behave like that.

Comment: I have change the dp to this new PropertyMetadata(new User() { Name = "Another", Age = "18" })); and removed the CurrentUser = new... and it works, how did you instance the CurrentUser?

Comment: Sorry I read should now I have arrived to what you were explaining, it is curious. let's analize that

Comment: Yes it is mixing the datacontext with x:bind how curious isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Although it breaks the idea of MVVM a bit, you can add a property to your page like this:

```
public MainViewModel viewModel => DataContext as MainViewModel;
```

And then in the XAML code reference the page property

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{x:Bind viewModel.CurrentUser, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. CurrentUser is a dp in the page and not a property in the view model